# iOS, how to draw the dynamic length of text?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, uilabel

The picture is: http://www.flickr.com/photos/71607441@N07/6641626163/

The background is a UIImageView, and the blue part I want to show as "title" of the image.
I used UILabel, but the length of the text is dynamic. It can be one line or two line, at most two line. If the text is longer than two lines, it will be truncated.

The blue part looks like "highlight in Microsoft Word", but it is not "highlight in iOS UILabel.text"

Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :----

```
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 30);

UILabel *newsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
                    newsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    newsLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
                    newsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    newsLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                    newsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                    lineBreakMode:newsLabel.lineBreakMode];
                    CGSize dateStringSize = [@"Text Input" sizeWithFont:newsLabel.font 
                                                                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                                                           lineBreakMode:newsLabel.lineBreakMode];
                    CGRect dateFrame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, dateStringSize.height); //breath can be any desired float value


                    newsLabel.text = @"Text Input";
                    newsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
                   newsLabel.frame = dateFrame;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code. It is not what I want. In the last line, if it is short, I want the label cut in the middle. So there may be two UILabel to resolve it. But I don't know to how to draw the first line, how to draw the second line, how to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the size in pixels required for your title using:

```
CGSize size = [UILabel.text sizeWithFont:yourFont];
```

there's also:

```
CGSize size = [UILabel.text sizeWithFont:yourFont lineBreakMode: yourLineBreakMode];
```

You could then use these dimensions (size.width, size.height) to set the frame of your UILabel.

Hope this helps. :)